# Problems with rebex sftp file deletion

Tags: sftp, rebex

I'm get a `SftpException: No such file; File not found.` when using Rebex sftp's `Sftp.DeleteFile(string filename`) which is especially odd because I'm first checking that the file exists.

Here's the relevant sample code:

```
foreach (var file in fileList)
{
    if(ftp.Connection.FileExists(file.Name))
    {
        try
        {
            ftp.Connection.DeleteFile(file.Name);
        }
        catch (SftpException ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Deletion failed.", ex);
        }
    } 
    else
    {
         Log.Debug(string.Format("'{0}' not found.", file.Name));
    }
}
```

Rebex's online docs can be found [here](http://www.rebex.net/help/) for those not familiar with the library.

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Comment: Usually the library just translates server's error message. Did you try with Rebex support (they are responsive)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David also asked this question on our support forum at http://forum.rebex.net/questions/1635/sftpexception-no-such-file-file-not-found

I'm recording the solution here too, because it can be handy in similar situations.

- The file does exists on the SFTP server
- Application opens a stream which locks the file on server
- The file cannot be deleted and server reports "No such file; File not found." error message
- Closing those streams resolves the issue and file can be deleted now.

Unfortunately the SFTP server error message was not very helpful in this case. One could ask if something like "access denied" would not be more appropriate.